# Multi-part form upload using Alamofire and BOX API

Tags: xcode, swift3, alamofire, box-api

I am having a very hard time trying to get this to work.  I am trying to upload a file to Box as per their API instructions in the [Getting Started section](https://docs.box.com/docs/getting-started-box-integration)

I am using Xcode 8, Swift 3 and Alamofire 4 framework.  I've googled and searched stack overflow.  I feel like I am close, but the file upload it still not working.

I keep getting an error from the BOX API saying:

> [Result]: SUCCESS: {
>       code = "bad_request";
>       "context_info" =     {
>           errors =         (
>                           {
>                   message = "'parent' is required";
>                   name = parent;
>                   reason = "missing_parameter";
>               }
>           );
>       };

Here is my code

```
func testUpload() {


    let endpoint = "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content"

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer \(tempDeveloperToken)"
    ]

    let jsonAttributes = JSON(["name": "test.pdf", "parent": ["id": "11774646649"]])
    let file = PDFService.getPDF(named: "document")            //Returns file as URL

    let paramAttributes = jsonAttributes.stringValue.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(paramAttributes!, withName: "attributes")
            multipartFormData.append(file, withName: "file")
        },
        to: endpoint,
        method: .post,
        headers: headers,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    )

}
```

I've tried many different ways to get add Params to the upload, what am I missing?

Comment: Finally figured it out and answered by own question. See solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of trial an error and spending hours on this thing to see what sticks, I finally got it to work.  Instead of passing the parameters as a JSON string, I decided to leave it as the documentation specified, but manually escaped every double quote in the string before encoding.  You can see in my solution I created a new variable called **"retest"** which was the fix to replace the old variable **"jsonAttributes"**.  I don't know if there is a better way to write this solution, but this worked for me.

```
func testUpload() {

    let endpoint = "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content"

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer \(tempDeveloperToken)"
    ]

    //let jsonAttributes = JSON(["name": "test.pdf", "parent": ["id": "11774646649"]])
    let retest = "{\"name\":\"test.pdf\", \"parent\":{\"id\":\"11774646649\"}}"
    let paramAttributes = retest.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) //jsonAttributes.stringValue.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let file = PDFService.getPDF(named: "document")            //Returns file as URL


    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(paramAttributes!, withName: "attributes")
            multipartFormData.append(file, withName: "file")
        },
        to: endpoint,
        method: .post,
        headers: headers,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The multipart form looks correct. You might try removing the `parent` *header*. It doesn't need to be there.

Comment: ooops, the parent header was something I forgot to remove.  I've removed it, but doesn't seem to be the issue.  This is bugging me, based on all my research, my code looks correct.  Not sure why the API is rejecting it.

Comment: Gotcha. Please capture an HTTP trace of the request using something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/introducing-fiddler-for-os-x-beta-1) so that we can see what's going over the wire. Your code does like right, but there might be a non-obvious serialization issue.

Comment: After throwing everything I could at this issue, I finally got it to work.  Solution is pretty surprising but it worked.  Will post the solution shortly.

Comment: Ok, glad you're unstuck. Your solution suggests there was some sort of serialization issue after all. If it was me, I'd take the time to root-cause the problem by a) inspecting the stringified version of the JSON and maybe b) looking at an HTTP trace of the request. You'll probably need to use the built-in JSON serializer eventually...

Comment: Ya, I should prob do some root-cause analysis.  I would hate to have to manually escape quotes every time I need make an API call with parameters.  Even though it is "safe" since I can see it even before compiling, kind of a pain.  Thx for your inputs though, helped pave the way.